# Generated meta tags fail w3c validation

Tags: html, wakanda

I'm checking some markup for an app we're working on, and one of the wakanda-generated meta tags fails the W3C validation.

```
<meta name="WAF.packageJson">
```

The validation service is stating that the "Element 'meta' is missing one or more of the following attributes: content, property."

I am considering setting an arbitrary value for 'content' to pass the validation, but was wondering if there is a better way to do this for these particular tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the WD2 migration meta tag. It's added by default to your Pages to indicate that the Page be delivered using Wakanda WD2.

The correct solution is either remove it either fill it with [dummy data](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Architecture-of-Wakanda-Applications/Page/Packagejson-File.300-1023864.en.html). I suggest the latter.

If this meta tag is present, a `package.json` file is created and maintained for the Page. This file contains the **page's dependencies**, which are all the files that Wakanda Server needs to send over with the page when it is requested.

If you want to specify a specific package.json file, you can do so by specifying it in the content parameter:

If you want to disable the WD2 for one of your Pages, you can either remove the  tag or modify its name so that WD2 does not find the "WAF.packageJson" name property in the Page.

You can find more information regarding this in the [package.json doc](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Architecture-of-Wakanda-Applications/Page/Packagejson-File.300-1023864.en.html) and on the [html page doc](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Architecture-of-Wakanda-Applications/Page-Prototype/HTML-File.300-1023732.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

From W3Schools:

> The content attribute MUST be defined if the name or the http-equiv attribute is defined. If none of these are defined, the content attribute CANNOT be defined.

The content attribute IS required here, there may but should be no workaround for this in the validation. You will need to add a content for your `<meta>`-tags.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, though this is generated by the stack. I can arbitrarily add a content attribute, but I mainly need to find out what the best practice is when using this software